# The meaning of a 'mark' in here

Tags: word-meaning

> Out the window, Mamah could see four children, her own plus Emma
>   Barton and Frankie, Jennie and Andrew’s son. When the four of them
>   weren’t out riding, they were in the barn hanging around, helping Tom
>   Brunker groom the horses. Tom was **a tender mark**—a widower, with young
>   children of his own over in Milwaukee. There was another draw for
>   Martha and John in the barn, too: the imminent birth of a foal.

from *Loving Frank* by Nancy Horan

What is the meaning of a **'mark'** here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mark is someone who you trick or fool. A conman, for instance, will look for "an easy mark"--someone who they are able to deceive. In this context, the kids aren't trying to fool or con anyone out of anything, but because Tom is a widower and has kids, he gives the kids attention where other adults might not. Thus he's their "mark," the person they focus their attention on in order to get something.